# preg_replace error at the time of upload multiple image in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, preg-replace, image-uploading

I got error while uploading multiple image in laravel.

HTML Code :-

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="title">Art Gallery</label>
 <input type="file" name="art_image[]" id="art_image" value="{{old('art_image') }}"  accept="image/*"  multiple="multiple">
</div>
```

:- Controller code

```
if ($request->hasFile('art_image')) {
   $fileImage1 = $request->file('art_image');
   $StoreName = array();
   foreach ($fileImage1 as $files) {
         $filename1 = time().rand(1,100).".".$files->getClientOriginalExtension();
     $StoreName[] = $filename1;
     if($files->move(ART_IMAGE_DIR_PATH, $filename))
         {
              $data['art_image'] = $filename1;
           }
        }
   $artdetail_model->art_image = serialize($StoreName);
     }
```

I got below error

preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array

Comment: Why don't you make a copypaste from your code, instead of REWRITING it? There is a uninitialized $filename variable that I guess in your original code is $filename1

Comment: Where is that preg_replace called from? What is the error stack?

Comment: ErrorException in helpers.php line 671:
preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array
in helpers.php line 671
at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array', '/var/www/html/MuseumManagement1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php', '671', array('search' => '\?', 'replace' => array(null, array(null), '11'), 'subject' => 'update `art_detail` set `art_cover_image` = , `art_image` = ? where `id` = ?', 'value' => array(null)))

Answer (score 0):

Problem is when you are submitting multiple images it becomes an array of pictures instead of a single string. So it is trying to save an array to the database instead of a string which it is expecting. If you make it so your photo variable is a **json_encoded** array of pictures then you should be able to save them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i am store serialize image array in database.what is the solution to remove this error?